# Unable to render json details using handlebar helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js

I'm trying to stringify an object to json and pass it to a template. But instead I see whole object as a string rather than only what I want.

Code

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("GetFBUserDetails", function() {

    var details = new Object({'fName' : firstName, 'lName' : lastName, 'pic' : pictureUrl});
    return JSON.stringify(details);

});

<li>{{#GetFBUserDetails}} 
              {{fName}}
    {{/GetFBUserDetails}}
</li>
```

I want only the firstname (fName) to be shown in li instead the whole object shows up as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply the template, you need to actually pass the result to the Handlebars processor.  Do this using the parameter (options) of the callback function to the object (not stringified):

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("GetFBUserDetails", function(options) {
    var details = new Object({'fName' : firstName, 'lName' : lastName, 'pic' : pictureUrl});
    return options.fn(details);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72sse/7/)

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify()` does what it's named after, it takes a JSON object and serializes it into a string. Handlebars uses objects, not strings.

This should do it:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("GetFBUserDetails", function() {
    return  {'fName' : firstName, 'lName' : lastName, 'pic' : pictureUrl};
});
```

Comment: tried it checked the dom and it showed.. <li>[object Object]</li>